Paint the background color of a cell based on an RGB code in another cell
Can someone provide the script for a formula that allows to paint the background of a range of cells, using the RGB code from another range of cells?
For example: if in D2 I insert =setbackgroundRGB(L2) the background of D2 gets the color from the RGB code in L2, if in D3 I insert =setbackgroundRGB(L3) the background of D3 gets painted with the color from the RGB code in L3. Please note that "setbackgroundRGB" is a made-up name for a customized function written in Google App script.

I'm not familiar with Google App Script but I hope someone can provide the script to obtain the formula described above.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is unclear whether you want to paint cells or get numeric RGB codes. Please show your manually entered desired results.

A custom function can not change the sheet format, including the background color of another cell.

As Haluk mentions, a formula is meant exclusively to return a value.

@Haluk Sounds like an answer.

Hi! I want to paint cells based in the RGB code in another cell @doubleunary

Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. Make sure you are not asking an XY question.

I want to paint cells based in the RGB code in another cell @Haluk has explained that you can't use your preferred method (=setbackgroundRGB(L2)) (a custom function) to do this. Conditional formatting is an option, as is a script (though slightly more complicated).

@doubleunary I did find the answer, but I cannot paste the answer as a comment because it is too long.
How can I provide the solution to the rest of the StackOverflow community?

You can always post an answer. See [answer].

This can be done by adding a script with a customized function.
In this version of the script the cells in the range "A2:A202"
(200 row starting from row2) get coloured with the RGB code in the equivalent row across columns B,C and D.
I like this formula because you can move around the input and output ranges (add/remove rows to colour, change the cell that gets coloured or their input) based on your needs, that is what I was looking for.
I hope this is helpful to others too!
function setRGBBackgroundColor() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Loop over the first 200 rows, starting from row 1
  for (var i = 2; i <= 200; i++) {
    var red = parseInt(sheet.getRange("B" + i).getValue());
    var green = parseInt(sheet.getRange("C" + i).getValue());
    var blue = parseInt(sheet.getRange("D" + i).getValue());
    
    // Check if RGB values are valid (numbers between 0 and 255)
    if (isValidRGB(red) && isValidRGB(green) && isValidRGB(blue)) {
      // Set the background color of column A for the corresponding row
      sheet.getRange("A" + i).setBackgroundRGB(red, green, blue);
    } else {
      // Clear the background if values are invalid or empty
      sheet.getRange("A" + i).setBackground(null);
    }
  }
}

